# How can I set up my own DHCP subnet on Rackspace?

Tags: networking, virtualization, rackspace-cloud, lxc

**Update:** *As per grawity and MonkeeSage's comments, it seems my question was pointed in the wrong direction. I've updated the title and question below...*

I'm currently evaluating LXC as an option for my company to safely and easily deploy several client projects to a single virtual server hosted on Rackspace. All the articles I'm reading use Bridged networking + DHCP to give each container its own IP on the local network. Unfortunately, this isn't an option on Rackspace since they do not allow a virtual machine to allocate any additional internal IP addresses.

How can I set up my own subnet that won't conflict with Rackspaces? The containers on each server must be accessible from other hosts on the Rackspace network and must be able to access the internet.

Comment: NAT + private address range + DHCP?

Comment: @grawity has the right idea, just be sure to use a different private subnet than 10.0.0.0/8 or you'll overlap with the subnet Rackspace uses for service network.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can really do this in the way you're describing.  If you're making up additional IPs, they have to be assigned to you by someone.  If you're doing NAT (acting as a "router"), then on that "virtual segment" you can use any IPs that you want, since nobody else will see them, but I'm not sure how this virtual segment would appear.